# In python how can i print only the first line of stdout which results from a shell command

Tags: python

in the following for loop, i print the version number of program installed

```
 for program in sub3_required_programs:
        try:
            version = subprocess.call([program, '-i'])                                                                     
            print version + '\n'
        except:
            exit
```

But i actually want only the first line which has the version number. How can i restrict the print to only the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the current print output? Unless you're running a version of Python that behaves differently, it looks like the return status of the call is the only thing being assigned to version.

> Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete, then return
>   the returncode attribute.

- [docstring for `subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

I bet the subprocess.call is the culprit, printing it's output to STDOUT. Even if you didn't have that print statement, you would still see all the output of the subprocess call due to the way the method works.

To grab the actual output, you might want to do something more like

```
lines = subprocess.Popen([program, '-i'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print lines.splitlines()[0] + '\n'
```

The `communicate` call returns the tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`. You can read more about it in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). Everything else should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
print version.split("\n")[0]
```

which gets first line (splitting on newline character) from the output.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `str.split('\n')` approach is that the newline character can differ across platforms. You might have better luck doing:

```
print version.splitlines()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at the newline character, and use only the first element of the resulting list:

```
 print version.split('\n')[0]
```

Comment: hmm still printing all lines :(

Comment: @kamal of course it doesn't work, it try to split on \n, not a newline because '\n' means two character: \ and n. To parse it as new line you have to use double quotes, which interprets it as newline character. You can obtain more information about quoting in Python from [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings). Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: @eduffy sorry, you're right. Then I don't know why your code is not working.